# Django Error while inserting null into date field

Tags: django

Am getting this error while updating date field to null in Django." 'Null' value has an invalid date format. It must be in YYYY-MM-DD format". Please help me if any one knows the solution.

Code:
            if editBirthday:
                editBirthday=datetime.strptime(str(editBirthday),"%d-%m-%Y").strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
                loggedInUser.Birthday = editBirthday
            else:
                loggedInUser.Birthday = "Null"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: At the time of user profile creation he given the dateofbirth but in edit profile if he wants to remove the dob from details.At that time i am trying to update dob to null into table.Then am getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not set the value to `"null"`, set it to `None`:

```
loggedInUser.Birthday = None
loggedInUser.save()
```

For this to work `Birthday` model field show be defined with [`null=True`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#null).

See also:

- [Django: How to set a field to NULL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4446652/django-how-to-set-a-field-to-null)
- [Django, Cannot assign None, does not allow null values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810745/django-cannot-assign-none-does-not-allow-null-values)